# Passing kernel params from U-Boot to ARM Linux when device tree is used

Tags: command-line, parameters, linux-kernel, arm, u-boot

I've been investigating a change to some embedded software inasmuch as we want U-Boot to be able to pass specific command-line parameters to the kernel, ones that aren't necessarily known in advance.

This is so that the kernel can tell *which* U-Boot partition it was started by (we have two copies, one in `/dev/mmc3boot0` and `/dev/mmc3boot1`, and they both share a single (redundant) environment space, so we can't use that alone to uniquely identify the instance).

One thought was to simply have each U-Boot write its ID to the shared environment when it boots but that has the downside that there are variants out there that do not currently do this. So, if we boot from one that does, it will write its ID and, if we then boot from one that doesn't, it will not *change* the ID back to blank, leading to incorrect information if we rely on that.

This is why we thought to use a kernel parameter - since older style U-Boot instances never supply an ID, we know it's running in `boot0`. The newer style would provide their actual ID so we could then search the two `boot` partitions to see which one it was in.

To that end, I've modified U-Boot so that it sets up ATAGs to pass through the extra parameter needed. Specifically:

- I've define `CONFIG_SYS_BOOT_GET_CMDLINE` in `arch\arm\include\asm\config.h` so that `boot_get_cmdline()` is called.
- I've modified that `boot_get_cmdline()` function so that it sets up a specific parameter *before* appending the normal parameters. In other words, rather than just `plugh=xyzzy`, we now get `uboot_instance=42 plugh=xyzzy`.

This all compiles fine and U-Boot successfully starts the kernel but the extra information is not being reflected in the Linux kernel, which has its kernel parameters set to the regular `plugh=xyzzy`.

On further research, it appears that we are falling afoul of the two possible ways to invoke the kernel. One of these is with ATAGs and one is with a flattened device tree (FDT), and they appear to be mutually exclusive (the kernel startup code selects one or the other based on signatures passed in with the pointer referencing either the ATAGs or FDT structure).

So my question is this. Given that the device tree is meant to be a *fixed* structure for the device you're describing, how do you pass *arbitrary* kernel command line parameters (calculated at runtime) when the bootloader is invoking the kernel?

Comment: @sawdust. The problem is really the shared environment in conjunction with the fact we will have legacy U-Boots. We *could* get the new-style ones to always write their ID but, if we subsequently reverted to an old-style, there's nothing in them that clears out that data, so it would be inaccurate. I've updated the question to make that clearer. The use of a separate kernel parameter will work simply becaue old-styles will provide nothing and new-style will provide something we can search for. It may end up that we just have to bite the bullet and refuse switching back to an old-style.

Comment: You can use a dummy environment variable for your platform in `include/configs/&lt;board.h&gt;`. For example, `bootconf = &quot;uboot_instance = X&quot;` as default value and append this in bootargs. During the initialization of the board, you can set this variable using `env_set` API, specifically by writing your own custom `board_late_init` of the board init code in `board/&lt;vendor&gt;/&lt;start_up.c&gt;`. By this way, you don't need ATAGS.

Comment: Sorry, I meshed my comment. But still the logic remains correct.

Comment: @Parthiban: do you mean changing our `mmcargs` env-script from `setenv bootargs console=${console},blah` into `setenv bootargs ${sneaky} console=${console},blah` and defining `sneaky` as `id=42` in those files? If this would be stored in the UBoot environment area (ie, persistent), we still have a problem. But if it's set for new-style and not for old-style, that could work.

Comment: @sawdust: that might work. If we get each new-style UBoot to write a variable when it boots but not `saveenv`, a reboot to an old-style will naturally see that variable disappear. And, of course, any new-style will create a new instance of the variable as it boots.

Comment: Yes, by using `env_set` you won't save it. The value will be again default in next boot until otherwise changed in `board_late_init`

Comment: Just one more bit of sneakiness needed, I think. We have the ability to change environment from the kernel itself. I guess in that case, we'd modify that facility so that it remembered the variable, deleted it, made its changes, saved those changes, then recreated the variable. That way, the variable could never be persisted. That'll just be a slight mod to uboot-tools, I guess.

Comment: It might be worth putting these options into answers so I can start handing out rep :-)

Comment: Sure :-) Stackoverflow for Android is not that friendly yet for me. Will do shortly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a dummy environment variable for your platform in `include/configs/<board>.h`.

For example, assume you have the following (simplified) UBoot environment variables for booting:

```
bootcmd=run mmcargs
        run loadimage loadfdt
        bootz ${loadaddr} - ${fdt_addr}
mmcargs=setenv bootargs blah=blah
```

This uses `mmcargs` to set up the kernel command line to use. What we need to do is to insert that dummy environment variable in a way that current UBoot instances supply nothing and new ones supply the actual ID. This is done simply with the following change:

```
mmcargs=setenv bootargs ${uboot_id_stanza} blah=blah
```

Then, during the initialization of the board, you can set this variable using `env_set` API, specifically by writing your own custom `board_late_init` of the board init code in `board/<vendor>/<init_code>.c`.

The following line should be placed at the end of the `board_late_init` function:

```
setenv("uboot_id_stanza", "uboot_id=<uniqueId>");
```

That way, the `uboot_id` variable setting is added to the kernel command line but, since you didn't do a `saveenv`, it doesn't become persistent. Every UBoot instance will set the correct ID (including old ones that *don't* set an ID).

Comment: No reason you have to give the variable a default value if "empty" is ok.

Comment: Let me see if I understand this. In `board/<vendor>/<board>.c`, we already *have* `board_late_init` (configured in `include/configs/<board>.h`). You propose we `setenv("ubstanza","ubid=42")` from there, and modify `bootargs` in the persistent UBoot environment to be `${ubstanza} original-bootargs`. That way, old UBoots won't have a `ubstanza` so `bootargs` will be `original-bootargs`. New UBoots *will* have the stanza so `bootargs` will in all cases have that stanza. My only question is: does `ubstanza` persist over boots or is it ephemeral to the current boot?

Comment: The reason I ask is that we *want* that stanza not to persist if, for example, we revert to an older UBoot (that will neither clear it nor set it to another value). So, ideally, `bootargs` would persist and `ubstanza` would not.

Comment: One final note, I assume `board_late_init` is actually done *before* running `bootcmd` from the environment since that latter action does a `bootz` as part of it (`bootcmd` calls `mmcboot` which calls `loadimage/loadfdt/bootz`) so will not return.

Comment: Yes it's called very early during initialization here https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot/blob/master/common/board_r.c#L809. So you should not be having any troubles in getting access to the variable in Kernel. Using `env_set` or `setenv` does the same in setting the variable for the current boot and it will _not_ be saved to your persistent storage. You have to use `env_save` or `saveenv` command to save it separately.

Comment: Parthiban, this worked wonders. I hope you don't mind that I modified your answer to match what was done to solve it. I thought that better than adding my own answer.